# Parsing from URL with NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, xml, swift, nsxmlparser

I am making an app that should parse an XML file from URL.

For now, I just want to know the basics how things work. I know that it might seem you as a very very simple, but as being a newbie at it, some things are still difficult to understand, but I have done some simple apps already.

Although I have looked up NSXMLParserDelegate Protocol, I do not know how to use those examples...

I want to parser from this URL:

> http://jpg.tartu.ee/tunniplaan/xml/periood1.xml

I have also looked others questions at the same topic, but I can not figure out those solutions and they are not exactly what I am looking for. Therefore, I am asking a specific question.

Comment: Just a note on your xml, lines 448-471 and 477-482 attempt to redefine an attribute which is invalid xml since you cannot have two attributes with the same name on the same tag (the `Period` attribute in the `TimeTableSchedule` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Note : The link you provided is not working.
Consider a simple example.

```
<Class>
  <Student>
    <Name>John Snow</Name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Name>Harvey Specter</Name>
  </Student>
</Class>


- (void)viewDidLoad{
      NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"yourURL"];
      NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
      [parser setDelegate:self];
      BOOL result = [parser parse];
}

// Following methods are the NSXMLParser delegate methods :

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

   //Document Starts...

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

   //Document Ends...

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    //This method detects a tag(eg. <Name>)

    NSLog(@\"Did start element\");
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"]){
    NSLog(@"name tag");
    // set current tag as "Name" tag
    return;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    // if current tag is Name

   if([currentTag isEqualToString:@"Name"]){
       //Take text, JohnSnow or HarveySpecter
       NSString *text = string;
   }
}

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
   // Detects end of tag.(eg. </Name>)

    NSLog(@"Did end element");
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"]){
          NSLog(@"Name end");
          // Do what's necessary..
        }
   // set current tag as nil
}
```

P.S. You can also create a view dynamically by parsing an xml. i.e, if "button" tag (like "Name" above) is detected then a UIButton can be created (frame and button title can be provided within the xml.). Similarly for UILabel, textField.

Comment: I think he wanted a Swift answer.

Comment: Sorry. Still i hope its helpful for some people. Peace !!

Answer (score 0):

Add the delegate to your view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {
```

Then to parse a url with xml:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://jpg.tartu.ee/tunniplaan/xml/periood1.xml")
let xmlParser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url!)!
xmlParser.delegate = self
xmlParser.parse()
```

Also add the delegate function for parsing (I've added an example of how to print an element's name to the console.

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    print("Element's name is \(elementName)")
}
```

Note that because your xml is accessed via http and not https you may run into errors. I would first suggest you switch your server to using https, but for quick testing [you can add something to your `info.plist`](http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error) to get it to work via http for now.

Comment: I can't switch the server to using https. Could you think of any another way that how I could access the xml file? with url it's just convenient.

Comment: And on the line - 

let xmlParser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url!)!

It says an error that "instance member "url" cannot be used  on type "ViewController""

And another error says on line - \n

xmlParser.delegate = self "Expected declaration" What should I do?

Comment: Well you could always store the xml on the phone if it's unlikely to change.

Comment: Should I use AEXML parser instead? For reading local xml files ?

Comment: You can still use the NSXMLParser, just make the NSURL using fileURLWithPath: